# How do I make a comment in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am writing a Dockerfile. Is there a way to make comments in this file?

Does Docker have a comment option that takes the rest of a line and ignores it?

Comment: I'm finding that if a layer is cached, commenting it out has no effect: Docker continues to build commented out layers if already cached.

Answer (score 763, accepted):

You can use `#` at the beginning of a line to start a [comment](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format) (whitespaces before `#` are allowed):

```dockerfile
# do some stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    # install some packages
    && apt-get install -y cron
```

`#`'s in the middle of a string are passed to the command itself, e.g.:

```dockerfile
RUN echo 'we are running some # of cool things'
```

Comment: So the answer to the second question, *"Does Docker have a comment option that takes the rest of a line and ignores it?"*, is no? *"[Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format)"*.

Comment: Can you update your answer and make it more comprehensive/complete? For instance, answering the second question.

Comment: [BMitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123446/249226) fills in critical information that is missing in this answer.

Comment: linking to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564598/how-can-i-add-comments-in-long-docker-run-commands

Comment: As the documentation mentions: "For backward compatibility, leading whitespace before comments (#) and instructions (such as RUN) are ignored, but discouraged." You should add the comment at the beginning of a line... https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format

Answer (score 164):

As others have mentioned, comments are referenced with a `#` and are [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format). However, unlike some languages, the `#` must be at the beginning of the line. If they occur part way through the line, they are interpreted as an argument and may result in unexpected behavior.

```
# This is a comment

COPY test_dir target_dir # This is not a comment, it is an argument to COPY

RUN echo hello world # This is an argument to RUN but the shell may ignore it
```

It should also be noted that [parser directives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#parser-directives) have recently been added to the Dockerfile which have the same syntax as a comment. They need to appear at the top of the file, before any other comments or commands. Originally, this directive was added for changing the escape character to support Windows:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/nanoserver
COPY testfile.txt c:\
RUN dir c:\
```

The first line, while it appears to be a comment, is a parser directive to change the escape character to a backtick so that the `COPY` and `RUN` commands can use the backslash in the path. A parser directive is also used with [BuildKit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/) to change the frontend parser with a `syntax` line. See the [experimental syntax](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) for more details on how this is being used in practice.

With a multi-line command, the commented lines are ignored, but you need to comment out every line individually:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM busybox:latest
RUN echo first command \
# && echo second command disabled \
 && echo third command

$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.04kB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> 59788edf1f3e
Step 2/2 : RUN echo first command  && echo third command
 ---> Running in b1177e7b563d
first command
third command
Removing intermediate container b1177e7b563d
 ---> 5442cfe321ac
Successfully built 5442cfe321ac
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning *"must be at the beginning of the line"*. What about line continuation? If a comment line ends with \, will the next line also be a comment? In other words, if a multi-line command were to be commented out, would all lines need to start with `#` or only the first line? An experiment suggests it is the former. This answer could be updated to cover that as well (making it even more awesome).

Comment: @PeterMortensen The comment is needed on each line, docker completely ignores everything up to the linefeed. What's interesting to me is that the multi-line command can span across comments.

Comment: For those considering editing the post for syntax highlighting, note that most of the code blocks above are Dockerfiles, not bash scripts, where the syntax highlighting is only distracting from the focus of the post.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `#` syntax for comments

From: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format

```sh
# My comment here
RUN echo 'we are running some cool things'
```

Comment: but can we comment on the same line as RUN, COPY, MAINTAINER, etc?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes according to the docs I linked to inline comments are valid  `ADD . $foo       # ADD . /bar`

Comment: @AlexanderMills note however that changing the comment at the end of the line will cause docker to rerun that line on a docker build, because the "line has changed". This can be useful and/or annoying

Comment: Very good point, perhaps docker should ignore the comment lol

Comment: That is both a feature and a bug, I guess Docker will consider it a feature, and I think that makes sense actually

Comment: Perhaps answer the second question, with an example?

Comment: A comment part way through a line is not a comment (see my answer) and therefore changing the content of the comment changes the command being run, which should break the caching.

Answer (score 16):

Dockerfile comments start with `#`, just like Python.
[kstaken has good examples](https://github.com/kstaken/dockerfile-examples/blob/master/mongodb/Dockerfile):

```sh
# Install a more-up-to date version of MongoDB than what is included in the default Ubuntu repositories.

FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Kimbro Staken

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install mongodb-10gen

#RUN echo "" >> /etc/mongodb.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongodb.conf"]
```

Comment: Yes, but unlike Python's not the rest of the line with a command in the beginning of the line? You may want to update your answer.

Comment: just a note: `MAINTAINER ` is deprecated, now advised to use labels: `LABEL maintainer="foo@abc.com"`

Answer (score 7):

> Docker treats lines that **begin with `#`** as a comment, unless the
> line is a valid parser directive. **A `#` marker anywhere else in a line
> is treated as an argument.**
>
> example code:
>
> ```sh
> # this line is a comment
>
> RUN echo 'we are running some # of cool things'
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> we are running some # of cool things
> ```

Answer (score 3):

### Format

Here is the format of the `Dockerfile:`

We can use `#` for commenting purpose, as for example `#COMMENT`

```sh
#FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
FROM microsoft/dotnet
COPY /publish /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

From the above file when we build the docker, it skips the first line and goes to the next line because we have commented it using `#`

Answer (score 2):

```
# this is comment
this isn't comment
```

is the way to do it. You can place it anywhere in the line and anything that comes later will be ignored