# FROM requires one or three arguments Docker

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I run `docker build -t imagename .`

I get the following error :

```
 Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04 
 ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9 RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \ 
 && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \ | 
 tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
 && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn ENV MAVEN_HOME 
 /usr/share/maven VOLUME /root/.m2 CMD ["mvn"]
        **FROM requires either one or three arguments**
```

Can anyone tell me what I should to fix this. I downgraded from 17.12 to 17.06 so that I dont get `Bad Response from Docker Enginer` when I build. Others work fine. I can pull and run other images. I can't build. Please help and suggest a fix thank you!

My docker version is

```
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```

Docker info is:

```
 Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.06.2-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7
runc version: 810190ceaa507aa2727d7ae6f4790c76ec150bd
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.41-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB
Name: moby
ID: 3S5I:DUOJ:EBRI:PRH6:VMBJ:6H3K:OBZB:HFH7:7RSH:XEO5
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2018-01-15T16:10:58.5589804Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker file is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

VOLUME /root/.m2

CMD ["mvn"]
```

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that Docker treats your entire Dockerfile as a single line. The snippet you've provided have proper line terminators - is it the case for the original file as well?

Comment: What end of line characters are you using in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use **ARG**, so instead of just

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9
```

change to

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.9
```

Comment: sure.. glad could help.. if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was caused by having a Dockerfile with CR line-endings on Windows. Converting to CRLF or LF solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the same cause as with the problem the OP had, I had the exact same error after following a tutorial.

Turns out said tutorial had comments at the end of each config line e.g.
FROM python:3 # the base image

On removing the comments, all was fine (turns out a '#' must be at the beginning of a comment as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710459/how-do-i-make-a-comment-in-a-dockerfile)).