# How can I add comments in long docker RUN commands?

Tags: bash, docker

I know it's customary to have run-on RUN commands in docker files to reduce steps/space.  However, as these get long, I'd also like to add more comments to make the command clear.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \   # I WANT A COMMENT on what this step is doing
 && apt-get install -y software-properties-common # comments also don't work here, before the slash \
```

What's the docker/bash syntax or docker convention that would allow comments next to individual steps? If I put the comment where indicated above, I get the error

```
$ sudo docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 5: unknown instruction: &&
```

Which makes sense from a bash perspective but leaves me with few options for communicating the intent of the line.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to have a line with only the comment:

```
# comment 1
RUN apt-get update \
    # comment 2
    && apt-get install blabal blabla blabla \
    # comment 3
    && echo this is not a drill
```

docker removes the comment line with the newline.

See [docker-nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/1fe92b86a3c3a6482c54a0858d1fcb22e591279f/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile) with examples.

Comment: See also the [dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format)

Answer (score 7):

If you want comments on the same line as the commands, you can use this syntax:

```sh
RUN apt-get update -y          `# comment1` \ 
&& apt-get install -y          `# comment2` \
    software-properties-common `# comment3` \
    curl                       `# comment4`
```

or

```sh
RUN apt-get update -y          $(: comment1) \ 
&& apt-get install -y          $(: comment2) \
    software-properties-common $(: comment3) \
    curl                       $(: comment4)
```

Comment: I came up with this, too (only worse :-)), but the other answer is much cleaner.